# How to create a caption for a pure CSS/HTML Slider with thumbnails, no java/jquery

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a slider that has image thumbnails that you use to navigate with. I also want to create a caption for each slide, to appear and disappear with their specific slides.

This is what I have at the moment, http://jsfiddle.net/yb02jzbq/

(Sourced from http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-image-slider-with-stylized-thumbnails)

As you can see it's just missing the captions, if you remove the `id="d-slide1"` in one of the first divs, you will see what I'm trying to achieve. I'd prefer if the captions also followed the main images effects (if easier than scaling, could you make it slide in from right to left?)

Comment: Captions were never implemented, what I've been trying to do was when you click a thumbnail a new slide appears, with it the caption also appears. The slide is set up in a way that uses <input> and pseudo elements i.e. :checked.

The problem is how to create captions that change when you navigate via clicking the thumbnails. I appreciate any help you can offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response. I think I solved your problem. First I changed your titles to `class='d-slide'` in order to remove dependency on id's and counters(for unique IDs). Also instead of a gazillion lines for each ID, you use:

```
.d-slide{visibility:hidden; display:inline-block;}
```

After that's it's easy. This line does the trick for me:

```
.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label+img+.d-slide { 
    visibility: visible; 
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yb02jzbq/1/).

Comment: Wow, very nice! Works perfectly. I haven't dwelled much in making a slider from just css, thanks for that! I'll just tinker with it for some effects, thanks again.